# User Authentification not working for Apache Server on Docker

Tags: docker, apache, authentication

I want to add user authentication to my existing Apache web server. The Apache web server is running on a Docker container with the image httpd:2.4.41. I have created a password file in advance which is working. I have done the following configurations:

httpd.conf file:
Moduleimport

```
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
```

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl/server.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl/server.key

    <Directory "/var/index.html">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
    
   
</VirtualHost>
```

There are no errors in the container log, but I do not get a user authentication field.